# Symfony validate a property if another property is not not blank

Tags: php, validation, symfony

**I have a class**

```
Class SubjectSegment{ 
 /**
 *@CustomAssert\MyCitizenshipNumber()
 */ 
 private $citizenshipNumber; 
 /**
 *@CustomAssert\MyDate()
 */ 
 private $citizenshipNumberIssuedDate;
}
```

what i really want to do is valid citizenshipNumberIssuedDate if citizenshipNumber is present...

What is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you should look on http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isCitizenDateValid"})
 */

Class SubjectSegment{ 
    /**
    *@CustomAssert\MyCitizenshipNumber()
    */ 
    private $citizenshipNumber; 
    /**
    *@CustomAssert\MyDate()
    */ 
    private $citizenshipNumberIssuedDate;

    public function isCitizenDateValid(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        //Do your validation here for your exemple :
        if(null === $this->citizenshipNumber && null === $this->citizenshipNumberIssuedDate) {
            $context->addViolationAtSubPath('citizenshipNumberIssuedDate', 'The date is required', array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i really required is to escape @CustomAssert\MyDate when (null == $this->citizenshipNumber ). i am using symfony 2.6

Comment: Your comment reply to your question `if(null === $this->citizenshipNumber && null === $this->citizenshipNumberIssuedDate) { // put $context->addViolation...  } `

Comment: In both cases if(null === $this->citizenshipNumber ) and if(null != $this->citizenshipNumber){} @CustomAssert\MyDate() is validating.

Comment: Is there any way that i can use @Assert\Expression{ this.citizenshipNumber != null , @Assert\MyDate() }... that would be great if we have such feature in symfony 2.

Comment: So remove your `/** @CustomAssert\MyDate() */` and add the validation in `isCitizenDateValid` method with your custom Assert Class.

Comment: I used group validation .. and it worked. Thanks paistra anyways

Answer (score 3):

You can archive this in two way:

1) callback validator (validated by a class method)

2) With a [class constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator)

I suggest the second way, so you must configure/set the validator to class scope like:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class MyCitizenshipNumber  extends Constraint {

...

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

}
```

so you can access to all class field member

Remember to put the validator on top of the class definition like:

```
/**
 *@CustomAssert\MyCitizenshipNumber()
 */ 
 Class SubjectSegment{ 

 private $citizenshipNumber; 

 /**
 *@CustomAssert\MyDate()
 */ 
 private $citizenshipNumberIssuedDate;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: what i need is to call constriaint MyDate only when citizenshipNumber is not  blank.. class constraint validator.

Comment: You want to call the date validator inside the citizenshipNumber validator? if so  take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337427/symfony2-call-emailvalidator-inside-a-custom-validator). If this is your solutions probably you must inject the `validator` component inside the citizenshipNumber validator

Answer (score 3):

```
Class SubjectSegment{   

    /**  
    *@CustomAssert\MyCitizenshipNumber()  
    */  
    private $citizenshipNumber;   

    /** 
    *@CustomAssert\MyDate(group={"is_my_citizenship_number"})  
    */   
    private $citizenshipNumberIssuedDate;

    public function getGroupSequence(){ 
        $sequence = ['SubjectSegment']; 
        if(null != $this->CitizenshipNumber){ 
          $sequence[] = 'is_my_citizenship_number'; 
        } 
        return $sequence; 
    } 
}
```

validator:

```
$violations = $container->get('validator')->validate($segment = new SubjectSegmet(), null,$segment->getGroupSequence() );
```

Comment: It would be nice if symfony introduces Assert  inside Expression.. Code will be self explanatory.